# Subtle differences in Product Measures exercise

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X, M, \mu)$ a complete measure space. Let $f:X\to[0,\infty)$ be a measurable function and integrable function. Let $\psi(t)=\mu\{x
\in X : f(x) \geq t\})$. Prove that

> $$\int_X\!f\,\mathrm{d}\mu=\int_0^\infty\!\psi(t)\,\mathrm{d}t.$$

Now, we can see an answer here : [$\int_X g \, d\mu =\int_0^\infty\mu(x:g(x)>t) \, dt$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1449726/int-x-g-d-mu-int-0-infty-muxgxt-dt?noredirect=1&lq=1)

But the subtle difference is : In the link above $\psi(t)$ is defined for $x \in X$ such that $f(x) \gt t$ and not $f(x) \geq t$. Also it does not make use of complete measure hypothesis (I have an intuition this is useful for $f(x) =0$).

The question is : This subtle difference between the exercises makes the answer different?

Thanks.

Comment: Is $\int_0^\infty  \chi_{\{g(x) > t\}} \, dt $ different from $\int_0^\infty  \chi_{\{g(x) \ge t\}} \, dt \,?$

Comment: @KurtG. Is that a rethorical question?

Comment: Perhaps it was. More than that it  was a hint to go through all steps in the other [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1449726/int-x-g-d-mu-int-0-infty-muxgxt-dt?noredirect=1&lq=1)   to see if the proof with $\ge$ yields the same result as with $>\,.$ Too late. The given answer below got that hint.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to notice that
$$\int_0^\infty \mu(x: g(x)=t) dt=0$$
This follows from Fubini's theorem:
$$\int_0^\infty \mu(x: g(x)=t) dt=\int_0^\infty \int_X \chi_{\{g(x)=t\}} d\mu(x) dt=\int_X \int_0^\infty \chi_{\{g(x)=t\}} dtd\mu(x)=0$$
with the additional hypothesis that $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite.

Comment: What if the measure is not sigma finite?

Comment: @UDAC . The question in OP was if $\ge$ is a subtle difference to $>\,.$ The formula in the [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1449726/int-x-g-d-mu-int-0-infty-muxgxt-dt?noredirect=1&lq=1) you found assumes $\sigma$-finite and so should you from the beginning. If the measure is not $\sigma$-finite I'd rather hear your own thoughts on those problems.